# Delete, copy and modify a pom.xml file

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd

My pom.xml file with three different plugins: the first generates .java from .xsd, the second changes the .java from folder and the third deletes the originals .java

```
  ...
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                           <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/pt/thales/attracktive/communication/pojo</outputDirectory>
                           <resources>          
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc/uk/org/siri/siri</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.java</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                           </resources>              
                        </configuration>            
                    </execution>
                 </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                  <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                      <directory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/xjc/uk/org/siri/siri</directory>
                      <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                      </includes>
                      <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                  </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Questions:

1. Can I have a delete plugin and a change folder plugin? From what I tested I can't because the delete plugin is "stronger" and don't let the change folder plugin to act
2. When I change folder the package name also changes, is it possible to update it?
3. Why do I get this ERROR with this two .xsd

SubscriptionRequest.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="RequestorRef" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="MessageIdentifier" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="ConsumerAddress" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="SubscriberRef" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="SubscriptionIdentifier" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
      <xs:element name="InitialTerminationTime" type="xs:dateTime" />
    </xs:schema>
```

and TerminateSubscriptionRequest.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.siri.org.uk/siri" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="RequestTimestamp" type="xs:dateTime" />
  <xs:element name="RequestorRef" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="SubscriberRef" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="SubscriptionRef" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
</xs:schema>~
```

Result:

> [ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [
>   file:/C:/Users/rapha/Desktop/Thales/attracktive-master/thales.attracktive.communication/attracktive.communication/src/main/resources/TerminateSubscriptionRequest.xsd{4,54}].
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   file:/C:/Users/rapha/Desktop/Thales/attracktive-master/thales.attracktive.communication/attracktive.communication/src/main/resources/TerminateSubscriptionRequest.xsd;
>   lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 54; 'RequestorRef' is already defined

I tried different thigs but it didn't result probably I'm missing something.
Thanks for the lecture and if you can help me please

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by copying and removing the generated java files? To me it seems what you actually want is to generate the files into a different package, which is better accomplished by configuring the jaxb plugin. The error you’re getting is because both schema files define the same namespace and declare the same element, hence the duplication message.

Comment: That's exacly what I want! How can I chose a different package? And how can solve my 3rd problem, the duplication message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the package, you can use the `generatePackage` option for the jaxb2 plugin, as described in [the plug-ins docs](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin) .
If you require something more powerful (like putting different schemas in different packages), you’ll need to use jaxb2 bindings files as described in [the jaxb docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/custom.html).

The duplicate element error is due to both of your files declaring the `RequestorRef` element in the same namespace.
You can fix this by either:

- Merging the two files, which seems to be the best option since the namespace is the same
- changing the namespace in one of the files so they don’t clash. This would make sense if the duplicated elements are actually different elements